# Deploying java class files without restarting JBoss

Tags: java, jboss

I would like to know if its possible to deploy java class files without restarting JBoss server. I am using jboss v4.2.2.

Also, when I try to deploy jsp files, it works fine and server picks up the changes almost instantly.

Thanks a lot in advance :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm better with Tomcat than JBoss, but it should be possible (as in Tomcat) to restart the application without restarting the app server. If the server has a "development mode" and this is active, then it should be possible to trigger an app restart simply by `touch`ing `WEB-INF/web.xml`, i.e. updating its timestamp. That should get your previously replaced class file loaded.

Comment: Thanks for the clue! That actually does the trick. 
Here is more info for the same:
http://community.jboss.org/wiki/RedeployAnApplicationWhenChangeAFileInAnExplodedDeploymentDirectory

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically, you never have to restart the whole server, you only restart specific applications (ear-s). JBoss (with default settings) will automatically redeploy your ear if it notices any changes in it. Just copy the new version over it.

If you're not using it already, check out JBoss Tools set of eclipse plugins, to simplify whole process of deploys during development: http://www.jboss.org/tools

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to re-deploy your class files without stopping and starting the server each time.

The only thing you have to do is to make a junction or a symbolic link to the application directory (in eclipse is usually "WebContent") and put the name you want in Jboss.

I've made a step-by-step tutorial [here](http://www.supermanhamuerto.com/doku.php?id=java:hotdeploymenteclipse).

Comment: How exactly is this meant?

Comment: To create a symbolic link in windows, the command is like this: mklink /d NAME-OF-SYMBOLIC-LINK "NAME-OF-DIRECTORY"

Answer (score 0):

Deploy the app as exploded (project.war folder), add in your web.xml:

```
<web-app>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.jboss.weld.development</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
```

Overwrite the web.xml every-time you deploy:

```
set PRJ_HOME=C:\Temp2\MyProject\src\main\webapp
set PRJ_CLSS_HOME=%PRJ_HOME%\WEB-INF\classes\com\myProject

set JBOSS_HOME= C:\Java\jboss-4.2.3.GA-jdk6\server\default\deploy\MyProject.war
set JBOSS_CLSS_HOME= %JBOSS_HOME%\WEB-INF\classes\com\myProject

copy %PRJ_CLSS_HOME%\frontend\actions\profile\ProfileAction.class %JBOSS_CLSS_HOME%\frontend\actions\profile\ProfileAction.class
copy %PRJ_CLSS_HOME%\frontend\actions\profile\AjaxAction.class %JBOSS_CLSS_HOME%\frontend\actions\profile\AjaxAction.class

ECHO.>>%JBOSS_HOME%\WEB-INF\web.xml
```