# In what cases is it required to restart JBoss server?

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss, restart, hotswap

While any change is done to a deployed/live application, what are the cases when we need to 'restart' the 'JBoss server'?
viz.
  - if just hot-swap of some(.js/.css/.jsp) file is done.
  - if some class is replaced.
  - if I replace the complete .war file.
    ...etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you could restart just the deployed application, and not the entire `JBoss AS`. You can find some more information about this in the [JBoss community](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/RedeployAnApplicationWhenChangeAFileInAnExplodedDeploymentDirectory).

Also some other interesting information regarding this can be found in this question:

[Deploying java class files without restarting JBoss](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2738342/deploying-java-class-files-without-restarting-jboss?rq=1)

If you copy a new `war` file onto the server it should redeploy it automatically if that functionality is enabled. This will cause the application to restart, but not the entire server. Depending of caching settings on different levels (browser, proxies etc) you might be able to swap some files without doing anything else, but this can be a bit tricky to control, hence restarting the application is probably the best way to make updates.

Hope it can help you forward.